Is there a way to read push notifications coming from a page in selenium?
I would like to read the push notifications sent from a web page. I am using Selenium with Python and Firefox. To be more specific, i am not talking about permission popups or alerts, but actual push notifications sent to the desktop of the user.
The conditions I am working with are very specific, that being I am running my selenium app within a headless docker container, and the application needs to be out of focus for the push notifications to be sent. For this reason, setting up dbus to work with Firefox is a real pain, and I would like a way to read the notifications from within selenium itself.
Is there a way for me to read the push notifications from selenium, be it through hooking a function in javascript or otherwise? Thank you.
